# Installing MongoDB on Windows 8

Tags: mongodb, discord.js, windows-8.1

I am trying to install MongoDB to use for my discord.js bot. I need it desperately and since I am using a shared computer, I am not able to update windows. When I downloaded MongoDB and tried to open the installer, it said "Windows version must be 10+ to support MongoDB". And then the installer closes automatically and says "Installation failed."

Please advise.

Comment: Are you talking about MongoDB Compass?

Comment: Nope just the regular one that you're supposed to download in https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I made was that I installed the latest version of MongoDB so instead, for anyone using any version of Windows that is less than 10, install mongodb version 4.2.15.